PostgreSQL 17: pg_upgrade on Windows Server 2019: could not load library "$libdir/adminpack": No such file or directory

Installed PostgreSQL 17 from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads.

Switched off postgres 13 and 17 Windows services.

Gave read and write permissions to both bin and data directories in both 13 and 17.

pg_hba.conf changes in both 13 and 17.

local   all             all                                     trust

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Ran pg_upgrade with check flag: pg_upgrade -b "Drive:\PostgreSQL\13\bin" -B "Drive:\PostgreSQL\17\bin" -d "Drive:\PostgreSQL\13\data" -D "Drive:\PostgreSQL\17\data" -p 5432 -P 5433 -v -U postgres -c

Error: could not load library "$libdir/adminpack": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/adminpack": No such file or directory

Checked the Drive:\PostgreSQL\17\lib directory for adminpack.dll. This DLL is absent in postgres 17 but is present in 13, 15, 16 versions of postgres. Tried copying each version of the DLL to 17 but 17 detects the version of adminpack.dll.

Checked pgAdmin 8.12 directory. No adminpack.dll.


I am stuck at this point. Where do I find the postgres 17 version of adminpack.dll?
EDB installer for postgres 17 does not contain adminpack.dll which is stopping pg_upgrade.

Correct: the "adminpack" extension does no longer exist in PostgreSQL v17, as you can see in the list of incompatibilities in the release notes:


Remove adminpack contrib extension (Daniel Gustafsson) §
This was used by now end-of-life pgAdmin III.



You will have to remove the extension in v13 before you can upgrade:
DROP EXTENSION adminpack CASCADE;


Thanks Laurenz. Just tried it out. 13 upgrade to 17 upgrade works now.

Seems like that should've been mentioned in the migration notes

@GammaGames You are right. I'll try to make it happen.

@GammaGames ...and done in commit a8b2402041. It should become visible soon.
